# Drop-Down CSS Menu (sub-links hide)

Tags: drop-down-menu, css

can anyone tell me what I have done wrong in creating this vertical CSS dropdown menu. The sub-level "hides" under the CSS quote element underneath. The CSS menu has been sought and uses styled lists.

Would this be a Z index issue or positional issue or am I just a doughnut?

Here is the code link on Pastebin : http://pastebin.com/CBuT532G
(I can never copy my code into the code option here, which doesn't bode well!)

Gutted I can't show a screen grab!
Cheers

Comment: make it in jsFiddle and I will take a look

Comment: Cheers man. Hope this helps show what I mean. http://jsfiddle.net/Fsyzk/

Comment: Both answers appear to be right- which one do I mark as correct (don't have enough rep to mark both answers as useful)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add z-index 1 in your dropdown-menu css

```
ul.dropdown-menu {
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    display: table;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: So it was the z-index (something I struggle to get my head around) This worked nicely, thank you Sonasish.

Answer (score 0):

Make instead of `<ul class="dropdown-menu">` to `<ul class="dropdown-menu" style="z-index: 999;">`

Works for sure! :)

Comment: sorry for my late respond thought! atleast still the awnser ;)

Comment: No problem with response times Ryan - any feedback is good no matter what time. This worked nicely, thank you.